# Actualizar CDUs da tabela moedas

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para integrar com o Primavera ERP V9 e quando para a tabela/objecto moeda e não consigo actualizar a CDUs atraves do seguinte codigo.

```
if (currencyId != 0)
{
     currency.EmModoEdicao = true;

     var fieldToUpdate = new StdBECampos();

     //Update the CDU_Portal 
     fieldToUpdate.Insere(new StdBECampo { Nome = "CDU_Portal", Valor = 0 
});

//Update with data Id on procu4U. 
fieldToUpdate.Insere(new StdBECampo { Nome = "CDU_procu4U_entityId", Valor = currencyId });

                                        PriEngine.Engine.Comercial.Moedas.ActualizaValorAtributos(currencyCode, fieldToUpdate);
                                        PriEngine.Engine.Comercial.Moedas.Edita(currencyCode);
}
```

Consigo com as mesma instruções para a tabela unidades.
Alguem sabe como posso ultrapassar? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde,
Isto pode ser feito desta forma:

```
currency.CamposUtil.get_Item("CDU_Portal").Valor = 0;
PriEngine.Engine.Comercial.Moedas.Actualiza(currency);
```

Comment: Bom dia, Obrigado!